# How do I make all validate() calls to execute in a controller?

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-5

In a controller I am using two validation like this:

```
public function update(Request $request){

if( $request->hasFile('img1') ){

    $request->validate(
        [   
            'img1'=>'image'
        ]
    );


}


if( $request->hasFile('img2') ){

    $request->validate(
        [   
            'img2'=>'image'
        ]
    );


}
}
```

Now if I upload incorrect file types for both img1 & img2 Only the first validation is checked and laravel redirects user to the original form page. This way message for only first validation is displayed. Even though second file type was also incorrect. I want to make sure all validate methods are checked are executed before I get redirected to the page I came from i.e., the page containing form.

Also I can't put validate method for file in one `if statement` as `img1` and `img2` might not be present at the same time. Because user might just want to upload one file.

Comment: also show your form fields

Answer (score 0):

You need not invoke validate method more than once for validating a single request. In the validate method you can validate all the inputs from the request, and if the validation fails, then it will automatically return the page which the request came from. And also you need not check whether the request has the input or not, before the validation. It will automatically be managed by laravel.
In the following validation `required` is used to specify the field is mandatory, and it will only accept file types specified in `mimes`, and `max` is used to specify the maximum file size in kilobytes.

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'img1' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:1000',
        'img2' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:1000',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'img1' => 'required_without:img2',
        'img2' => 'required_without:img1'
    ]);
}
```

If have more than two fields and only one is required, use `required_without_all:foo,bar,...`